# Autocomplete Jquery реакция на совпадение введенного значения

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

У меня есть два блока

```html
<div class="connecter-content">...</div>
<div class="unchecked-connecter-content">...</div>
```

И зависимые поля, заполняющиеся при помощи Autocomplete

```html
<input id="streetName_online" type="text" placeholder="Улица" value="" name="streetName" >
<input id="houseNumber_online" type="text" placeholder="Дом" value="" name="houseNumber" autocomplete="OFF">
```

Поле houseNumber_online при вводе в него значения дома при совпадении должен выводиться блок matched, при несовпадении unmatched, причем, например, в базе есть дом номер 1, мы вводим 1 и появляется блок matched, вводим дальше 2, то есть дом 12 (его нет в базе), прячется matched и выводится unmatched

```js
j('#streetName_online').on('change', function(){
  var arr = j('#streetName_online').map(function(){
    return j(this).val();
  }).get();
  j( "#houseNumber_online" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/modules/mod_connect/autocomplete_houseNumber.php?street=" + arr,open:function(event,ui){
      if(true)
        j("#connecter-content").css("display","block");
      else 
        j("#unchecked-connecter-content").css("display","block");
    }
  });
});
```

Пока я написал такой код, но он не рабочий.
В итоге должно быть как на этом сайте http://cosmostv.by/connection/connect

Answer (score 1):

Событие change срабатывает при потере фокуса, т.е. 10 раз ввели какие-то символы в текстовое поле, а обработчик вызовется лишь при переходе на следующее поле

Может лучше подойдёт событие keyup, только не забудьте отфильтровать всякие ctrl, shift, esc и т.п. (f5 =) )

```js
$('.rchange').on('change', function() {
  console.log('change');
});

$('.rkey').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
On change:
<input class="rchange" />
<br />On key:
<input class="rkey" />
```

---

*PS: смущает if(true) в вашем коде*